# Max occurance of characters in a java string not using array please

Tags: java

i need to find the maximum occurance of characters in a string in java but if there are more than one character that have more than one occurance. it will print that first character. for example if i try aabbb it will print a: 2 instead of b: 3. i do not know how to use array. please give me advice.

```
    int count = 1;
    int max = 1;
    String newstring = "";
    String currentletter = "";
    String finalletter = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
        currentletter = word.substring(i, i+1);
        if (newstring.contains(currentletter)) {
            currentletter = "";
        } else {
            newstring += currentletter;
            for (int j = i+1; j < word.length(); j++) {
                if (currentletter.equals(word.substring(j, j+1))) {
                    count++;
                    finalletter = currentletter;
                }
            }
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                count = 0;
                currentletter = "";
                System.out.print(finalletter + ": ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max + " ");
}
```

Comment: Not using an array?  Take a guess at what `String` is backed by ;)

Comment: Just to confirm: for  `aabbb` the correct result should be`b: 3` (that's how _I'd_ interpret "maximum occurrences"), but it's actually giving the wrong result of `a: 2` ?

Comment: Yes. The result should be b: 3 but my code gave me a: 2.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`Map<Character, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and **two** loops. First, populate the `map` by iterating the `String` and counting the occurrences of letters. Second, iterate the *entry set* of the `Map` and compare it with a local maximum. Finally, display the result (or a message indicating no result). Like,

```
String s = "aabbb";
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    map.put(ch, 1 + map.getOrDefault(ch, 0));
}
Map.Entry<Character, Integer> max = null;
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (max == null || max.getValue() < entry.getValue()) {
        max = entry;
    }
}
if (max != null) {
    System.out.printf("%c: %d%n", max.getKey(), max.getValue());
} else {
    System.out.println("no result");
}
```

And I get

```
b: 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't learned map yet. Is there a simpler way? Is there anything wrong with my original code? Thanks.

Comment: @IanDong *Is there anything wrong with my original code?* [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662298/max-occurance-of-characters-in-a-java-string-not-using-array-please/50662414?noredirect=1#comment88335208_50662298).

Comment: It looks like you need to do some _debugging_.  Here are some [free tips](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to help you get started.